# How to make a Report Folder publicly available for everyone in the org?

Tags: custom-reports

Title says it all: How to make a Report Folder publicly accessible for everyone in the org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'everyone in the org' you mean all internal users, then there's already a public group you can share the report folder with to do this.

Following the [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rd_folders_share_enhanced.htm&type=0), you can go to `Reports --> All Folders`

Right click on the down arrow at the right side of the folder and select `share`

[image]

Now, on the sharing screen, you can select **Public Groups** to share with. Search for `All Internal Users` and it should eventually display (might take a second). Select that group and set the `Access` to view.

[image]

Now, all internal users have view access to that folder.